# Деление файла на блоки.С++

Tags: visual-c++

Здравствуйте) Сегодня разбираю деление файла на блоки. Размер блока приходит от клиента. Только это приходит в буфер как строка, нужно в число преобразовать (1).
Что в самом делении файла и помещении в буфер неправильно?

```
int a = atol(buffer);(1)

//Отправка файла
int i = 0;
while(!feof(in)) 
char * buff = new char[a];
{ 
  int b=fread(&buff,1,sizeof(buff),in); 
  int size=ftell(in); 
  printf("Bytes read: %d, part:%d, pos: %ld \n",b,i,size); 
  if(b!=0) 
  send(client_socket,&buff,b,0); i++; 
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте понять, что вы только что спросили :-)

Comment: char * buff = malloc(размер) или char * buff = new char[размер]. После этого не забыть вызвать free() или delete[]. Но в вашем коде всё равно проблемы в другом :)

Comment: @АннаХатико Или Вы неправильно скопировали текст, или одно из двух. Попробуйте определить тело циклв while (то, то между фигурными скобками, к циклу уже не относится)

Comment: @АннаХатико, вот так (если буфер размером `a` уже выделен и без анализа ошибок), будет правильно

    while(b = fread(buff,1,a,in))
        send(client_socket,buff,b,0);

постарайтесь сами разобраться (достаточно прочесть про while и fread) почему.

Comment: а как тогда перемещать указатель в файле?

Comment: @АннаХатико Недавно это тут уже обсуждали. Указатель (который внутренний) будет перемещаться во время чтения fread. Поскольку Вам не надо пропускать части файла (или посылать их несколько раз), то нормальное последовательное чтение Вас должно устроить.

Comment: то есть вот этого цикла 


    while(b = fread(buff,1,a,in))     
    send(client_socket,buff,b,0); 


на стороне сервера вполне достаточно?

Comment: Если всё остальное правильно, то да. Если там будут ошибки, то нет.

И моё высказывание на тему "дурят нашего брата" остаётся в силе -- в трубу тупо заливается весь файл и размер куска при этом значения не имеет, а соответственно у клиента и сервера этот размер может быть разным.

Comment: Делаю так 


    b = fread(buff,1,a,in);


почему-то  b = 0


    in = fopen(filename, "r");


    int b; 
    while(b = fread(buff,1,a,in))  
    {
  send(client_socket,buff,b,0);
  i++;
     printf("Отправляем %d блок файла \n", i);
    }

Comment: Ну, в 

    while(b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in))

я немного ошибся. Надо писать

    while((b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in)) > 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Всплывает то, о чём писал [@avp](/users/232/avp): надо разделять информацию. Поскольку tcp -- это труба, а от пользователя приходит путь к файлу(1) и размер блока(2), то их надо чем-то отделять друг от друга (например '\n' или '\0')
2. Тут постоянно всплывают вопросы про динамическое выделение памяти. Если язык -- C, то используется чаще всего malloc, если C++ -- то new.
3. Преобразовать из char* в int/long можно используя atoi/atol (или масса других способов).
4. Если нет явных требований к наличию разделителей в потоке содержимого файла, то преподаватель немного обманывает вас и/или себя. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char * buff = new char[a];
...
int b=fread(&buff,1,sizeof(buff),in);
```

sizeof(buff) в данном случае вернет размер указателя (4 или 8 байт), а не размер массива